# Why do I get a yarn memory error?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

In HDP 2.6.3, Spark 2.2 and Zeppelin 0.7.3 I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required executor memory (12288+384 MB) is above 
the max threshold (8192 MB) of this cluster! Please check the values of 
'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.
```

`yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` is at its maximum (8GB).

I have 4 nodes with 16GB each, so I have `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` = 14.25GB.

I have tried:

`export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.memory=2g -Dspark.cores.max=7"`

with no luck.

The problem is the `12288`, how do I reduce that?
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You can always raise `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` which should be identical to `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`.  8 GB is the default, not the max.